# What is the Markdown editor used on this site?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I'm a real **Markdown** fan, and I would like to know if the editor used on this site is available as a plugin/etc. to use on other websites.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is.  Check out [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) here.

The newer changes incorporated into the  sites are pushed to [pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).

There's a [wmd](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wmd) tag on http://meta.stackoverflow.com for discussions about its use with the SE sites.